# How to install Broadcom Wi-Fi on Arch Linux in command line mode?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, command-line, drivers

How do I install Broadcom Wi-Fi on Arch Linux in command line mode on an Acer eMachines EM350?

I assume that Broadcom STA should be the driver used and my USB key the way to install it with the help of another PC, assuming that I can't use a RJ45 ethernet connection on LAN.

Comment: Did you follow the Archwiki Beginners guide? Specifically where you isntall the wirelesstools package? That is the first step. Also, have a look at this page https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_Setup - It may help guide you.

Comment: I have wirelesstools installed, I now need to build the STA drivers with my usb key to bring it in my archlinux in command line ...

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would build an Arch package and then install it from your USB with pacman. 
[Here is the link for building packages in Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_Packages)
**Remember build on same architecture and kernel(if you can)

Then tell Pacman to use your usb drive as a source

```
#pacman -U /mnt/media/yourusb/STApackage.pkg.tar.xz
```

Comment: I can't use that option, I'm stuck in command line without internet access ...

My GF laptop to help me but ...

Comment: I meant build it on another Arch machine. If you don't have access to one then you're going to have to see if the Arch build tools are available on the cd you used to install. I don't know if they are or not. then use the Source from broadcom and build it locally. See here for how to setup a cdrom as a local mirror: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Tips#Installation_and_recovery - Also search the wiki and message boards they are extremely helpful.